# Escaping quotes and diacritics in Neo4j query

Tags: c#, .net, neo4j

Let's say I have the following query passed to Neo4j as string in a C#/.NET application:

`MATCH (e)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(t:Tenant) WHERE t.id={id} AND ( e:Unit OR e:UnitInactive ) AND e.name contains {queryName} RETURN e`

How do I format the query string to retrieve an specific **e.name** like **"Mary's"** or **"João"**, escaping quotes and diacritics and case-insensitive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can treat special characters (diacritics) as regular chars.  Then single quote in Mary's can be escaped with \.

For example, in neo4j cypher:

```
 toLower(e.name) = "joão" OR toLower(e.name) = "mary\'s"
```

[image]

Comment: But this way it works with any word that have ' and special characters? Is there a way to format the string with the query before to send to neo4j?

Answer (score 0):

In case the query is used in a programming language (e.g. python), I think the recommendation way would be using [parameter](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/#cypher-parameters-introduction). For instance:

`e.name contains $queryName`

And when calling the session query:

`session.run(query, queryName=NameValue)`